# How can I tell if a <textarea> is empty in an Angular 8 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a text area like so:

```html
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="form_message">Message * (Minimum if 15 characters)</label>
          <textarea
            id="form_message"
            required
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Message *"
            rows="6"
            formControlName="form_message"
          ></textarea>
          <div
            *ngIf="
              form_message.invalid &&
              (form_message.dirty || form_message.touched)
            "
            class="alert alert-danger"
          >
            <div *ngIf="form_message.errors.minlength">
              Message must be at least 15 characters.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In the first `*ngIf` I would like to check to see if the length of the text in the `<textarea>` is greater than zero to prevent the red box from appearing with no text in it when the `<textarea>` is dirty, but the user has deleted all the text.

I used to do this with ngModel, but that has been deprecated.

How do I tell that a `<textarea>` has no text in it?

Comment: `form_message.errors.required` will be true when the field is empty. As long as you're using the required validator.

Answer (score 2):

You [can use ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) for this use case

**Template**

```
<textarea
  id = "form_message"
  required
  class="form-control"
  placeholder = "Message *"
  rows = "6"
  formControlName = "form_message"

  [(ngModel)]="formMessage"
></textarea >
```

**Component**

```
let formMessage;
```

If you have a big form with many inputs, [take a look at angular reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like `this.FORM_NAME.get('form_message').value.trim().length` should do the trick.

Comment: !this.FORM_NAME.get('form_message').value == true --> if the textarea empty or contains just ""